# Closed form solution for Quadratic Recurrence Relations

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, closed-form

I was trying to solve the following recurrence relation using *method of generating function* but I couldn't.

> $$a_n=a_{n-1}^2-a_{n-1} +1$$
>   for $a_0=2$ and $n>0$.

After googling I found it is the recurrence for **[Sylvester's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester's_sequence)** ([A000058 OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000058)).

In wikipedia the $n^{th}$ term of sequence is given by $$a_n=\lfloor E^{2^{n+1}}+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor$$ 
where $E=1.264084735305302$ approximately.

So my questions are

**a)** Whether the above has a perfect *closed form solution* or not ?

**b)** If yes, is $E$ rational or irrational ?

**c)** Is there a way to tell if the given recurrence relation having *quadratic form*($a_n=pa_{n-1}^2+qa_{n-1} +r$) has *closed form solution* just by looking at the coefficients ?

Comment: Those quadratic terms are quite tricky; among other things, such recurrences are unlikely to exist in a closed form

Comment: Here https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00651136v1 you can find a proof for the irrationality of $E$.

Comment: Note also that every quadratic recurrence is linearly conjugate to a recurrence of the form $x_{n+1}=x_n^2+c$.

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer to part C.

Currently, we know how to iterate two types of quadratic sequences. They are for quadratics in one of these two forms:
$$q_1(x)=ax^2+bx+\frac{b^2-2b}{4a}$$
$$q_2(x)=ax^2+bx+\frac{b^2-2b-8}{4a}$$
See the wikipedia page on [iterated functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function) or [this blog post](http://nilknarf.langlab.org/entries/2017-11-4.html) for a more in-depth explanation of how to iterate these two types.